# A long query tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, oracle-ebs

I have the following query, in this query, I am selecting the ebs tables, with a custom table which has header_id and populating the the data in a custom table XXREPORT_L1_TBL.

I want to tune this query.

[update] made changes to the query as bellow:

1. splited the query in 3 different insert statements
2. removed the columns which do in line queries for values
3. added an update statement at the end for these columns.

   ```
   insert into XX.XXREPORT_L1_TBL ( ORDER_NUMBER 
                                           , LINE_NUMBER
                                           , UOM
                                           , CUSTOMER_LENGTH
                                           , THEORETICAL_WEIGHT
                                           , FINISH
                                           , ORDER_QTY_PCS
                                           , ORDER_QTY_KGS
                                           , SALES_VALUE
                                           , TOTAL_VALUE
                                           , ORDERED_QUANTITY 
                                           , WIP_ENTITY_ID 
                                           , JOB_NAME
                                           , JOB_TYPE
                                           , JOB_STATUS 
                                           , JOB_RELEASED_DATE 
                                           , DATE_COMPLETED
                                           , DATE_CLOSED
                                           , JOB_CARD_QTY 
                                           , ALLOY 
                                           , PROFILE
                                           , PROD_QTY_KGS 
                                           , COST_KGS_THEORY 
                                           , COST_KGS_ACTUAL
       )

   SELECT 
    ---- Sales Order
      xx.order_number
      ,xx.line_number 
      ,xx.UOM,
      xx.customer_length,
      xx.theoretical_weight,
      xx.finish,
      xx.order_qty_pcs, 
      xx.order_qty_kgs,      
      xx.sales_value, -- total value / total kgs
      xx.total_value, -- line total
      xx.ordered_quantity,
    -- Production
      xx.wip_entity_id,
      xx.job_name,
      ( select case when a.inventory_item_id = 5716770 and a.job_type='NOT CHILD' then 'PARENT' 
               when a.job_type='CHILD' and a.inventory_item_id is null then 'CHILD' 
               when a.job_type='NOT CHILD' and a.inventory_item_id is NOT null then 'NOT CHILD' END JOB_TYPE 
        from ( select  disc2.wip_entity_id as wip_entity_id,      decode      (      nvl(disc2.attribute9,-1) , -1,'NOT CHILD', 'CHILD') job_type,      oel.inventory_item_id
                     from APPS.wip_discrete_jobs disc2,      APPS.oe_order_lines_all oel
                     where oel.line_id(+) = disc2.source_line_id
              )a
        where a.wip_entity_id = xx.wip_entity_id
      ) job_type, 
      ( select decode ( xx.status_type, 6, 'Open',
                                      3, 'Open',
                                      4,      'Completed',                                          
                                       LU1.MEANING )
               from APPS.FND_LOOKUP_VALUES LU1 
               where  LU1.LOOKUP_TYPE = 'WIP_JOB_STATUS'
               AND LU1.LOOKUP_CODE = xx.STATUS_TYPE
      ) job_status,      
      xx.job_released_date,
      xx.date_completed, 
      xx.date_closed
      ,xx.net_quantity as job_card_qty
      ,xx.alloy
      ,xx.profile
      ,xx.prod_qty_kgs      
        -- Theoretical Order cost  
      ,xx.cost_kgs_theory
        -- Actual Order cost      
      ,xx.cost_kgs_actual
        from (      
         select a.*
       -- Theoretical Order cost
               , DECODE (a.qty_completed * a.customer_length * a.theoretical_weight,0,0,
                   a.TOT_THEORY_COST_RELIEVED/(a.qty_completed * a.customer_length * a.theoretical_weight) ) as cost_kgs_theory 
       -- Actual Order cost
               , DECODE ( a.qty_completed * a.customer_length * a.theoretical_weight, 0, 0,
                   a.TOT_ACTUAL_COST_INCURRED/(a.qty_completed * a.customer_length * a.theoretical_weight )) as cost_kgs_actual
               from ( 

     select 
    -- Normal orders, INTERNAL Orders, Crimped Profile (parent jobs)     
      -- Sales Order      
           oeh.order_number as order_number
           ,oel.line_number
           ,oel.pricing_quantity_uom as UOM
           ,oel.attribute1 as customer_length
           ,oel.attribute6 as theoretical_weight
           ,oel.attribute5 as finish
           ,oel.attribute18 as order_qty_pcs
           ,oel.attribute7 as order_qty_kgs
           ,xx_om.GetLineUnitSellingPrice(oel.line_id) sales_value
           ,xx_om.GetHeaderUnitSellingPrice(oeh.header_id) total_value
           ,oel.ordered_quantity ordered_quantity
    -- Production                
           , tbl0.qty_completed as qty_completed
           ,disc.wip_entity_id as wip_entity_id
           ,( select wip_entity_name from APPS.wip_entities ent
               where ent.wip_entity_id = disc.wip_entity_id) job_name
           ,disc.status_type
           ,disc.date_released as job_released_date
           , DECODE ( disc.date_completed, NULL, disc.date_completed,
           -- my day Definition
           to_date(to_char(to_date(TO_CHAR(disc.date_completed-     interval      '7' hour,'DD-MON-YYYY')||'00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-YYYY      HH24:MI:SS'))      as      date_completed
           , DECODE ( disc.date_closed, NULL, disc.date_closed,
           to_date(to_char(to_date(TO_CHAR(disc.date_closed-     interval      '7' hour,'DD-MON-YYYY')||'00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))      as      date_closed
           , disc.net_quantity
      , ( select opr2.quantity_completed
            from APPS.wip_operations opr2
       where opr2.wip_entity_id = disc.wip_entity_id
       and opr2.operation_seq_num =       (select max(opr.operation_seq_num)
                                         from APPS.wip_operations opr, APPS.wip_discrete_jobs disc2
                                         where opr.wip_entity_id = disc2.wip_entity_id 
                                         and disc2.wip_entity_id =  disc.wip_entity_id))* oel.attribute1 * oel.attribute6 as prod_qty_kgs
           ,oel.attribute4 as alloy
           ,oel.attribute2 as profile

    -- Theoretical Order cost
             ,tbl0.TOT_THEORY_COST_RELIEVED
    -- Actual Order cost 
             ,tbl0.TOT_ACTUAL_COST_INCURRED
    from XX.XXREPORT_Lzero_TBL tbl0
    join APPS.oe_order_headers_all oeh on oeh.header_id = tbl0.header_id 
    join APPS.oe_order_lines_all oel on   oeh.org_id = oel.org_id and     oeh.header_id = oel.header_id
    join APPS.xx_assemblies asm on oel.line_id = asm.line_id
    join APPS.wip_discrete_jobs disc on disc.primary_item_id = asm.inventory_item_id
      where  oel.link_to_line_id is null

    union
    -- Crimped Child Jobs
     select 
    -- Sales Order      
           oeh.order_number as order_number
           ,oel.line_number
           ,oel.pricing_quantity_uom as UOM
           ,oel.attribute1 as customer_length
           ,oel.attribute6 as theoretical_weight
           ,oel.attribute5 as finish
           ,oel.attribute18 as order_qty_pcs
           ,oel.attribute7 as order_qty_kgs
           ,xx_om.GetLineUnitSellingPrice(oel.line_id) sales_value
           ,xx_om.GetHeaderUnitSellingPrice(oeh.header_id) total_value
           ,oel.ordered_quantity ordered_quantity
    -- Production
           , tbl0.qty_completed as qty_completed
           ,child_jobs.wip_entity_id as wip_entity_id
           ,( select wip_entity_name from APPS.wip_entities ent
               where ent.wip_entity_id = child_jobs.wip_entity_id)          job_name
           ,disc.status_type
           ,disc.date_released as job_released_date
           , DECODE ( disc.date_completed, NULL, disc.date_completed,
           to_date(to_char(to_date(TO_CHAR(disc.date_completed-interval      '7' hour,'DD-MON-YYYY')||'00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) as      date_completed
           , DECODE ( disc.date_closed, NULL, disc.date_closed,
           to_date(to_char(to_date(TO_CHAR(disc.date_closed-interval      '7' hour,'DD-MON-YYYY')||'00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) as      date_closed
           , disc.net_quantity
           , ( select opr2.quantity_completed
                 from APPS.wip_operations opr2
                 where opr2.wip_entity_id = disc.wip_entity_id
                 and opr2.operation_seq_num =       (select          max(opr.operation_seq_num)
                                                   from     APPS.wip_operations opr, APPS.wip_discrete_jobs disc2
                                                   where opr.wip_entity_id = disc2.wip_entity_id 
                                                   and disc.wip_entity_id =  disc.wip_entity_id))* oel.attribute1 * oel.attribute6 as prod_qty_kgs                
           ,oel.attribute4 as alloy
           ,oel.attribute2 as profile
    -- Theoretical Order cost
             ,tbl0.TOT_THEORY_COST_RELIEVED
    -- Actual Order cost 
             ,tbl0.TOT_ACTUAL_COST_INCURRED     
   from XX.XXREPORT_Lzero_TBL tbl0
    join APPS.oe_order_headers_all oeh on oeh.header_id = tbl0.header_id
    join APPS.oe_order_lines_all oel on oeh.org_id = oel.org_id and     oeh.header_id = oel.header_id
    join APPS.xx_assemblies asm on oel.line_id = asm.line_id
    join APPS.wip_discrete_jobs disc on disc.primary_item_id =     asm.inventory_item_id 
    join ( select wdj2.source_line_id, wdj2.attribute9 child_wip, wdj2.wip_entity_id, wdj2.status_type status_type
       from APPS.wip_discrete_jobs wdj2
       where attribute9 IS NOT NULL ) child_jobs on      child_jobs.child_wip = to_char(disc.wip_entity_id)
    where oel.link_to_line_id is null

     union
     -- Orders with star (*) items need to pick profile and customer      length etc from ego_configured_pr_agv view 
     select 
    -- Sales Order      
           oeh.order_number as order_number
           ,oel.line_number
           ,oel.pricing_quantity_uom as UOM
           ,to_char(agv.gx_cp_length) as customer_length
           ,to_char(agv.gx_cp_th_weight) as theoretical_weight
           ,agv.gx_cp_surfacetreatment as finish
           ,oel.attribute18 as order_qty_pcs
           , to_char(agv.gx_cp_th_weight * agv.gx_cp_length *          oel.ordered_quantity) as order_qty_kgs
           ,XX.xx_om.GetLineUnitSellingPrice(oel.line_id) sales_value
           ,XX.xx_om.GetHeaderUnitSellingPrice(oeh.header_id)      total_value
           ,oel.ordered_quantity ordered_quantity
    -- Production                
           , tbl0.qty_completed as qty_completed
           ,disc.wip_entity_id as wip_entity_id
           ,( select wip_entity_name from APPS.wip_entities ent
               where ent.wip_entity_id = disc.wip_entity_id) job_name
           ,disc.status_type
           ,disc.date_released as job_released_date
           , DECODE ( disc.date_completed, NULL, disc.date_completed,
           to_date(to_char(to_date(TO_CHAR(disc.date_completed-interval      '7' hour,'DD-MON-YYYY')||'00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) as      date_completed
           , DECODE ( disc.date_closed, NULL, disc.date_closed,
           to_date(to_char(to_date(TO_CHAR(disc.date_closed-interval      '7' hour,'DD-MON-YYYY')||'00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) as      date_closed
           , disc.net_quantity
      , ( select opr2.quantity_completed
       from APPS.wip_operations opr2
       where opr2.wip_entity_id = disc.wip_entity_id
       and opr2.operation_seq_num =       (select      max(opr.operation_seq_num)
                                         from APPS.wip_operations opr,      APPS.wip_discrete_jobs disc2
                                         where opr.wip_entity_id =      disc2.wip_entity_id 
                                         and disc2.wip_entity_id =       disc.wip_entity_id))* agv.gx_cp_length * agv.gx_cp_th_weight as      prod_qty_kgs
           ,gx_cp_alloy as alloy
           ,gx_cp_profile_id as profile
    -- Theoretical Order cost
             ,tbl0.TOT_THEORY_COST_RELIEVED
    -- Actual Order cost 
             ,tbl0.TOT_ACTUAL_COST_INCURRED

    from XX.XXREPORT_Lzero_TBL tbl0
    join APPS.oe_order_headers_all oeh on oeh.header_id = tbl0.header_id
    join APPS.oe_order_lines_all oel on oeh.org_id = oel.org_id and          oeh.header_id = oel.header_id
    join APPS.wip_discrete_jobs disc on oel.line_id =      disc.source_line_id
    join APPS.ego_gx_configured_pr_agv agv on agv.inventory_item_id=      oel.inventory_item_id
      where oel.link_to_line_id is null
           )a 
           ) xx;
   ```

Comment: No table structure, no index information, no information about the size of data, no execution plans. You need to at least provide some information. There is no magic button we can press to automatically tune queries.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975406/how-to-describe-performance-issue-in-relational-database) you may find the minimum requirement what you should provid in case of preformance problems ...

Comment: You could throw your query (and db connection etc.) at Leccotech db Expert and it will probably show you equivalent queries that run faster.

Comment: As others have said, without info on available indexes, execution plans etc - we are helpless. Only thing that jumps out based on the inline comments is that it looks like the two unioned datasets are never going to have a row that will appear in both sets. If true, then change UNION to UNION ALL to avoid Oracle having to test for that possibility. Also, the in-line query in the SELECT list can probably be improved.

Comment: The first step in performance tuning is to find what's slow.  You've found the query, now break it down into pieces and find out which piece is slow.  Break the query into 4 different parts - one for the `INSERT` and one for each query block separate by a `UNION`.  There's no need to post 227 lines of code if only a few dozen are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's almost certainly no short and simple solution to tuning this query. The problem here is it's size and complexity. Lack of performance is merely a consequence.

As a first step I would consider taking a break from the keyboard. Grab a pen and paper and in plain English (or whichever "human" language you prefer) write the questions you want answered from your database via this query. Then ask yourself *what columns/variables/attributes do you absolutely need to answer those questions?* Write them down as well.

Now, do you really need all of those columns, nested joins, selects, and so forth to produce those variables? Maybe, but probably not. The key point here is to focus on only the data/information you need (YAGNI) and from there map out a picture the bare relationships you need to produce the information that answer your question. In other words, work from the outside in, not the other way around.

I realize that this perhaps sounds a bit abstract and vague, but the whole point is that maintaining clear and simple code is always an ongoing struggle. Keeping your eye on the objective at hand will help keep your head of the weeds.

Finally, a few more specific thoughts at a glance:

- Do you really need that union? Try to do without it if you can.
- Nesting sucks. Nested nesting especially sucks. Keep things flat whenever possible and practical.
- Is it possible or practical to split this into independent, smaller queries?
- Use more descriptive names for your variables, add comments judiciously.
- Learn and master the SQL EXPLAIN command.

Comment: Let me try to divide the query in some pieces.